# Hide particular lines of algorithm2e code in beamer

Tags: beamer, indentation, algorithm2e, only, hide

I have a long algorithm that I present in my lecture and I want to distribute it over several frames to be able to slowly go through the details. I have the whole algorithm in an `algorithm2e` environment and could, of course, split it over several frames while utilising `\setcounter{AlgorLine}(x)` to adjust the line numbers to the omitted parts (or remove parts directly to have a more compact presentation as discussed at [Hide Input/Output in algorithm2e](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411934/hide-input-output-in-algorithm2e)). This is a bit cumbersome, as I have to duplicate the code several times and modify it depending on the parts which I want to show on the particular frame-slide. Another possible way is to use `scalebox` ([Using Algorithm2e package in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174631/using-algorithm2e-package-in-beamer)) but I do not like having too small fonts on a slide in my lecture that is barely readable.

Now it would be quite handy to specify somewhere which lines of this `algorithm2e` environment are shown / respectively omitted. So, this would not prevent having multiple copies, but at least I would not have to modify them explicitly and just mention which lines are shown.

Another benefit of this would be that one can show particular lines in the middle of the algorithm and keep the same indentation (when I modify the code, then I have to removed surrounding loops etc. which removes the indentation then).

Here is an example of the code. For instance, I want to show on slide

1. lines 1-8
2. 9/10
3. 12-18

I hope for a solution that somehow utilises the fact that `algorithm2e` uses, in principle (if I am not mistaken) the `itemize` environment that could maybe be used with beamer overlays (`only`) to show only particular parts...?

Here is a toy MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,noend,noline]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Algorithm 1}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \SetKwFunction{Test}{Test}
      \SetKwProg{Fn}{}{:}{}
      \Fn{\Test{$A,B$}}{
        \While{true}{
          \If{$X$}{
            line 1\;
            \If{line 2}{
              line 3\;
              line 4\;
              line 5\;
            }
            \If{$Y$}{
              line 6\;
            }
            \Else{
              \If{$Z$}{
                line 7\;
                line 8\;
                line 9\;
              }
              line 10\;
              line 11\;
              line 12\;
              line 13\;
            }
          }
          \lElse{do something}
        }
        line 14\;
      }
    \end{algorithm}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```